# Why does the Inkscape path outset tool behave in unexpected ways on my SVG image?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I have two objects of type path in Inkscape. Here's how they look:

[image]

My goal is to make them both “thicker”. To that end, I thought it would be a good idea to use the Path -> Outset tool. When I do that, however, this happens:

[image]

This is not quite what I'm aiming for. So I undid that operation. I also tried making a union of the two paths. Unfortunately, I then get this:

[image]

Which is also not exactly what I'd like. So my **questions** are:

1. How can I properly combine the two paths into one?
2. Once that has succeeded, how could I make the path (of the looped arrow) thicker as a whole? Is there something besides the Outset tool that can be useful in this case?

Comment: If this relates to your other question and our discussion, don't do that. It won't work.  If your paths have an orange stroke, all you need to do is group them, apply the outline filter to the group. To change the thickness of the strokes, change the stroke width in the Fill and Stroke panel.  Outsets only really work on closed paths, it won't affect strokes at all.

Comment: I note at this point you seem to have some difficulty understanding the concept of paths, strokes and fills, and especially the difference between a closed path with a fill, versus a path with a stroke. Perhaps it's time to have a look at a few online basic Inkscape tutorials which cover these topics. There are quite a few on youtube.

Comment: Looks to be that your failing for the same reason you couldnt do this in the XML in the first place.

Comment: @BillyKerr Alright, yes that's probably a good idea. I've watched quite a few videos by now, I think I'm slowly getting the hang of it.